# Difference between two SQLExceptions ("A transport-level error.." and "A network-related or ...")

Tags: sql-server, sqlexception

I have a bunch of users on my WPF/Linq2SQL application and I log all their exceptions at the database in a separate connection (which I create efter the exception has been thrown).

Occasionally I get the SQLExceptions:

1. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
   establishing a connection to SQL Server
2. A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server

To me, they both means that Linq2SQL were unable to connect to the database or was disconnected. But I assume there is some difference between them since Microsoft bother to have them both.

NB: It is not the server or the database which is the problem. One user may get crashed while the other 10 happily continues to work.

I know for a fact that 2) occasionally happens and I get nothing logged (because I log in a table on the same server/database) it seems logically that if the connection breaks down, I cannot save to the errorlog-table either. But both types of SQLExceptions do get logged occationally, meaning that a new connection is able to connect.

The user's setup is a laptop computer with both wire and wireless connections. They run windows. Occasionally my forget to disable wireless networking on their laptop when there's a cable to the machine. I have been told that this may cause trouble. Occasionally remember to disable wireless, but then they will disconnect their laptop from the network altogether to go to a meeting (where they re-connect).

I need help to figure out which exceptions should be ignored by the program, and which are important enough to let the program crash. And if I should bother re-try the operation before letting the program crash.

So.. basically I would like to know the difference between the two exceptions.

Comment: Exception 1 is that the program can't connect to the server to establish a connection, exception 2 is that it did previously manage to get a connection but it was interrupted.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the text in the messages really says so, too. So pulling the wireless connection from under the program may result in either exception..

Comment: Yep, depending where the program has got to at the time, you could get either. What might be worth doing is handling the error so that it retries the connection a couple of times and if this doesn't work, show a dialog box with a reconnect or quit button so that the user can either sort the problem and reconnect once they fixed the problem, or exit gracefully. Better than just letting it crash.